# How can I fill the table correct in Django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to fill the table in a correct way (see the picture).
But I can't do it without changing a model or using tables2 app.
How I can go through Teams and get 1 player for each team and then go next line for a table?
What I have now:
[Correct and wrong tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFvWo.png)

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Server(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Team(models.Model):
    server = models.ForeignKey(Server, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    n_players = models.IntegerField(null=True)

class Player(models.Model):
    server = models.ForeignKey(Server, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16, null=True)
    highlight = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Server, Team

def index(request):
    server_list = Server.objects.order_by('name')[:3]
    context = {'server_list': server_list}

    return render(request, 'monitor/index.html', context)
```

templates index.html:

```
{% for server in server_list %}
    <h2>{{ server.name }}</h2>
    <table>

        <tr>
        {% for team in server.team_set.all %}
            <th>
                <b>{{ team }}</b>
            </th>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>

        {% for team in server.team_set.all %}
            <tr>
                {% for player in team.player_set.all %}

                    <td>{{ player }}</td>

                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}

    </table>    
{% endfor %}
```

**Updated (10-30-19)**:
I tried to make another list from current classes in  views.py. But I could not do it properly. 
And now I have made another solution for it. 
In **views.py** I added:

```
context['range_1_7'] = range(1, 7)
```

It allows me go through for loop 6 times (because 6 is max number of player in a team).
And output columns and rows like this (templates):

```
{% for row in range_1_7 %}
                <tr>
                    {% for team in server.team_set.all %}
                        {% with team.player_set.all as player_list %}
                            <td>
                                {% if row == 1 %}
                                    {{ player_list.0.name }}
                                {% elif row == 2 %}
                                    {{ player_list.1.name }}
                                {% elif row == 3 %}
                                    {{ player_list.2.name }}
                                {% elif row == 4 %}
                                    {{ player_list.3.name }}
                                {% elif row == 5 %}
                                    {{ player_list.4.name }}
                                {% elif row == 6 %}
                                    {{ player_list.5.name }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </td>
                        {% endwith %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Of course it can seems as so bad solution, but it works.
It would be nice to figure out how to use a variable in a variable in django template like this:

```
{{ player_list.{{ row-1 }}.name }}
```

In this case it would be possible to remove the multiline IF-statement.

Comment: That's really hard using html tables because you have to "draw" them row by row and there isn't really a loop to go through. You can change what you pass to your template (so process the list in python in your view to create the rows and then pass the list of rows to your template). Or you can use flexbox divs so you can "draw" the columns (no <table> but using the flex css classes). That way you draw the columns from left to right and just list the players for each team vertically.